# React UnitTest with Ant Design Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have been struggling writing this unit test to test modal pop-up using Ant Design:

Function

```
import { Modal } from 'antd';
  handleMessage = (id) => {
      axios.get(`/messages/${id}`).then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200 && res.data) {
          if (res.data['results'] > 1) {
            Modal.confirm({
              title: `More than 1 message `,
              okText: 'Yes',
              cancelText: 'No',
              onOk(): {console.log('message'),
        }) }
```

Unit Test that i have been trying:

```
it('should display modal box', () => {
    axios.get = jest.fn()
    const res = "{data: {results: 2}, status: 200}"
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(res)

    handleMessage(1)

    let wrapper = shallow(<Modal />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper.find('.ant-body').toEqual()

  })
```

i am not able to find the modal box when the function is execute. Any help? thank you so much

Comment: shallow render won't render the actual HTML, you will probably need to use the `mount` method: https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html

Comment: Thanks. i have tried `mount` but its not working either...

Comment: Can you post what gets logged when you use wrapper.debug()